# Ruby hash of arrays, retrieving values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have been all over the interwebs and cannot seem to find out how to access an array within a hash. Plenty of ways to iterate through as well as flatten but no plain access.

```
hash = Hash.new()
data1 = "foo"
data2 = "bar"
hash["foobar"] = {data1, data2}
```

This all works, now **how can I access data1 and data2 *individually* within the hash**?

I was thinking puts `hash["foobar"][0]` should output `foo` but it returns `nil`.

Note: Every array in the hash will have Exactly 2 elements.

I know the answer is a simple 1 liner, I just cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Note: Ruby uses `[...]` for array literals, as opposed to `{...}` (hash literals). Fixing that (last line of your code) might help with your problem.

Comment: Eureka!!! That did it! Every site I went to was using curly braces.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Please throw that in an answer so I can check this off.

Comment: I was 6 seconds too slow :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented on the question, array literals are square brackets `[ ]`, not curly braces `{ }`. Change your last line to:

```
hash["foobar"] = [data1, data2]
```

(You were getting nil <strike>presumably</strike> because the hash literal had no `0` key. Testing [here](http://codepad.org/2MRtoP3H) reveals that `,` can apparently function as `=>` (*shudder*), so your iteral was equivalent to `{data1 => data2}`.)